# AWS EBS - disable "Environment health has transitioned..." emails

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I have a web application deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Apache Tomcat, and often receive environment health transition emails.

In my access logs, I'm finding lines like:

```
10.2.31.206 (183.196.36.238, 10.2.31.206) - - [28/Aug/2017:13:13:24 +0000] "HEAD /mysql/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
```

Does anyone know of a way to reduce the email spam other than switching from Enhanced to Basic Health Reporting? Perhaps completely blocking specific user agents or ignoring HTTP 4xx errors?

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible (Aug 2018) to configure health reporting to ignore HTTP 4xx errors:

> Elastic Beanstalk enhanced health reporting relies on a set of rules
>   to determine the health of your environment. Some of these rules might
>   not be appropriate for your particular application. A common case is
>   when frequent HTTP client (4xx) errors are expected, for example, as a
>   result of using client-side test tools.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-rules.html#health-enhanced-rules.console

Having said that, I seem to be able to get that to work, but get an error when visiting the "configuration" page for the environment (although `eb config <env>` works ok).